# HTML/CSS/jQuery Animated Skills Graph (Fiddle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a skills graph created that loads up to a certain "level."

Unlike a previous question, I want the graph to **animate when someone scrolls to the div** that is containing it (**so they can see the animation happen**).

Maybe activate the animation when they reach `<div id="myskills">` or within a few px of it.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/thomasmeagher/H7qUr/2/)

**HTML**

```
    <!-- Start Navigation -->
<nav id="nav_container">
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li><a href="#about">About</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#experience">Experience</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#myskills">Skills</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#education">Education</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<!-- Start Content -->
<div id="container">
    <!-- Start About -->
    <div id="about">
         <h1>About</h1>

        <div id="ab_container"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Start Experience -->
    <div id="experience">
         <h1>Experience</h1>

        <div id="exp_container"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Start Skills -->
    <div id="myskills">
         <h1>Skills</h1>

        <div id="skills"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Start Footer -->
<footer id="footer_container">
    <ul id="footer">
        <li>
            <p>Created by Name</p>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#about"><p>Back To Top.</p></a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
/****************************************************/

/* MISC SECTION */

/****************************************************/
 body {
    background:#FFFFFF url();
    margin:0px;
    font: 400 12px/22px'Open Sans', Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#6a6969;
}
h1 {
    font: 400 58px/60px'Bree Serif', Georgia, serif;
    color:#222222;
}
h2 {
    font: 400 18px/22px'Bree Serif', Georgia, serif;
    color:#6a6969;
}
h3 {
    font: 400 14px/16px'Bree Serif', Georgia, serif;
    color:#6a6969;
}
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
a:hover {
    color:#00FF00;
}
#container {
    width:850px;
    margin:0px auto 300px auto;
    overflow:auto;
}
/****************************************************/

/* NAVIGATION SECTION */

/****************************************************/
 #nav_container {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#222222;
    text-align:center;
}
#nav_container #navigation {
    padding-top:45px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}
#nav_container #navigation li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding-right:10px;
    margin-left:20px;
    font: 400 20px/5px'Bree Serif', Georgia, serif;
}
#navigation a.selected {
    color: #00FF00;
}
/****************************************************/

/* ABOUT SECTION */

/****************************************************/
 #about {
    padding-top:115px;
}
#about #ab_container {
    float:left;
}
#about #ab_container img {
    float:left;
}
/****************************************************/

/* EXPERIENCE SECTION */

/****************************************************/
 #experience {
    padding-top:115px;
}
#experience #exp_container {
    float:left;
}
#experience #exp_container img {
    float:left;
}
/****************************************************/

/* SKILLS SECTION */

/****************************************************/
 #myskills {
    padding-top:115px;
}
#skills {
    float: left;
    width: 40em;
    margin: 2em auto;
}
#skills div.row {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
#skills h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    height: 1em;
    line-height: 1;
}
#skills p {
    width: 0em;
    height: 1.5em;
    background: #00FF00;
    float: left;
}
/****************************************************/

/* FOOTER SECTION */

/****************************************************/
 #footer {
    position:relative;
    width:auto;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#222222;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}
#footer li {
    display:block;
    padding-right:10px;
    margin-left:20px;
    font: 400 16px/20px'Bree Serif', Georgia, serif;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

**JS**

```
    var Skills = new function() {

    var wrapper = document.getElementById('sk_graph');

    var $skills = {
        html5: '20em',
        php: '5em',
        jquery: '20em',
        wordpress: '18em',
        css: '20em'
    };


    var create = function() {

        var html = '';
        for (var i in $skills) {

            var skill = i;
            var value = $skills[i];

            html += '<div class="row">';
            html += '<h2>' + skill + '</h2>';
            html += '<p data-width="' + value + '"></p>';
            html += '</div>';

        }


        $(wrapper).html(html);

    };

    var animation = function() {
        var delay = 0;
        $('p[data-width]', wrapper).each(function() {

            var $p = $(this);
            $p.queue('width', function(next) {

                $p.delay(delay).animate({
                    width: $p.data('width')
                }, 600, 'easeInOutExpo', next);

            });

            $p.dequeue('width');
            delay += 300;
        });

    };

    this.init = function() {

        create();

        setTimeout(function() {
            animation();
        }, 500);

    };

}();


var skillsbar = false;

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {

    var skills_container = document.getElementById("skills");
    var skills_position = skills_container.getBoundingClientRect();
    var top_pos = (skills_position.top);
    var bot_pos = (skills_position.bottom);
    var scroll_position = document.body.scrollTop;

if (( scroll_position >= top_pos && scroll_position <= bot_pos)&&(skillsbar == false)){
    skillsbar = true;
    Skills.init();
    }
});
```

Comment: So **what have you tried so far?**

Comment: Haven't tried much so far. Thinking about trying to delay the animation until the browser window reaches `<div id="myskills">` so maybe change `var delay = 0` to something that allows me to do that? Like #myskills (not sure that will work at all). I'm pretty fresh to javascript.

Comment: Posting before having tried anything doesn't make me want to help you much...

Comment: @ZachSaucier I asked the question b/c I am stuck. I got up to this current point from *trying* AND look I created the animation and the graph! I could not find another topic on this so I asked after researching and providing two leads. You're more of another problem, than a solution currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, hope it will work for you:
(it doesn't work in jsfiddle)

```
var skillsbar = false;

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {

    var skills_container = document.getElementById("myskills");
    var skills_position = skills_container.getBoundingClientRect();
    var top_pos = (skills_position.top);
    var scroll_position = document.body.scrollTop;


    if (( scroll_position >= top_pos )&&(skillsbar == false)){
    skillsbar = true;
    Skills.init();
    }

});
```

I had to set global variable "skillsbar" to prevent animation from firing anytime scroll reaches div with skills bars.

Comment: Can I include the variable declaration in the skills.js file or should it be separate?

Comment: I think you can do that